# Drawing a rectangle between two points in OpenGL using scale + rotation matrix

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry

I have a rectangle mesh that I share in a flyweight type object that other classes use to draw themselves. The drawing code looks like:

```
void Draw(const glm::ivec2 position, const glm::ivec2 size)
{
    /* do some binding ...*/

    glm::vec2 s(m_screenDimensions.x,m_screenDimensions.y);
    glm::vec2 p(position.x,position.y);
    glm::vec2 d(size.x,size.y);
    glm::mat4 translationMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f),glm::vec3(-1.0f+p.x/s.x*2.0f+(d.x/s.x),1.0f-p.y/s.y*2.0f-(d.y/s.y),0.0f));
    glm::mat4 scaleMatrix = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f),glm::vec3(d.x/s.x,d.y/s.y,1.0f));
    m_program.SetUniform(m_modelMatrixLocation,translationMatrix * scaleMatrix * glm::mat4(1.0f));

    /* dispatch draw calls ... */
}
```

This easily draws a rectangle at the desired position and size. However, I'd like to now draw lines using this same rectangle flyweight. So basically:

```
void Draw(const glm::ivec2 position1, const glm::ivec2 position2, const unsigned int width)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

The problem I'm having is calculating the translation, scale and rotation matrix.

I understand that I can calculate the rectangle points via:

1. Getting a vector between the two positions
2. Getting a perpendicular vector
3. Placing each of the four around the positions moving along this perpendicular vector

But I don't understand how to calculate the rotation matrix needed. Obviously, because it's being expressed as a line (two points and a width) instead of as a rect (position and size) the way I'm calculating the translation matrix and scale matrix needs to be different to.

For example, if I calculate the translation and scale matrix as I am now (by deducing the size and position points from the provided positions and width); how do I calculate the rotation matrix?

**EDIT1**

I've tried as suggested but I'm not getting anything on the screen:

```
void RectColoured::Draw(const glm::ivec2 position1, const glm::ivec2 position2, const int width) const
{
    m_program.Bind();
    m_program.SetUniform(m_colorUniformLocation,m_color);
    m_program.SetUniform(m_useTextureUniformLocation,false);

 /*   glm::vec2 s(m_screenDimensions.x,m_screenDimensions.y);
    glm::vec2 p(position1.x,position1.y);
    glm::vec2 d(position2.x-position1.x+10,position2.y-position1.y+10);
    glm::mat4 translationMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f),glm::vec3(-1.0f+p.x/s.x*2.0f+(d.x/s.x),1.0f-p.y/s.y*2.0f-(d.y/s.y),0.0f));
    glm::mat4 scaleMatrix = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1.0f),glm::vec3(d.x/s.x,d.y/s.y,1.0f));
    m_program.SetUniform(m_modelMatrixLocation,translationMatrix * scaleMatrix * glm::mat4(1.0f));
*/
    glm::vec2 s(m_screenDimensions.x,m_screenDimensions.y);
    glm::vec2 d = position2-position1;
    glm::vec2 n = glm::normalize(d);
    auto p1 = position1;
    float w = width;
    float m[] = {
            2*d.x/s.x,  2*n.x/s.x*w,    0,  2*(p1.x-0.5*n.x)/s.x-1.0,
            2*d.y/s.y,  2*n.y/s.y*w,    0,  2*(p1.y-0.5*n.y)/s.y-1.0,
            0,          0,              0,  0,
            0,          0,              0,  1
    };
    glm::mat4 matrix = glm::make_mat4(m);
    m_program.SetUniform(m_modelMatrixLocation,matrix);

    m_quad.BindAndDraw();
}
```

**EDIT 2**
Not quite there:

```
void RectColoured::Draw(const glm::ivec2 position1, const glm::ivec2 position2, const int width) const
{
    m_program.Bind();
    m_program.SetUniform(m_colorUniformLocation,m_color);
    m_program.SetUniform(m_useTextureUniformLocation,false);

    glm::vec2 s = m_screenDimensions;
    glm::vec2 d = position2-position1;
    glm::vec2 n = glm::normalize(glm::vec2(d.y,-d.x));
    auto p1 = position1;
    float w = width;
    float m[] = {
        2.0f*d.x/s.x,                       -2.0f*d.y/s.y,                      0.0f, 0.0f,
        2.0f*n.x/s.x*w,                     -2.0f*n.y/s.y*w,                    0.0f, 0.0f,
        0.0f,                               0.0f,                               0.0f, 0.0f,
        2.0f*(p1.x-0.5f*n.x*w)/s.x-1.0f,    -2.0f*(p1.y-0.5f*n.y*w)/s.y+1.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f
    };
    glm::mat4 matrix = glm::make_mat4(m);
    m_program.SetUniform(m_modelMatrixLocation,matrix);

    m_quad.BindAndDraw();
}
```

Gives this result:

[image]

The two rectangle "nodes" have their top left corner as the two points of the line I'm trying to draw. I can see that it looks about twice as long as it should be along the direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to represent the line with a rectangle such that p1 and p2 are positioned on the middle of two opposing edges of the rectangle. Furthermore, I assume that your draw command uses the vertices of a 1 by 1 square with top left corner (0,0).

Then the position on the screen in pixel coordinates would be

```
p1 + d * x + n * w * (y - 0.5)
```

with d = (p2 - p1), n = normalize(-d.y, d.x) and w the width. By then converting to the opengl -1 to 1 range we get

```
vec2(-1.0, -1.0) + 2/s * (p1 + d * x + n  * w * (y - 0.5))
```

for screen dimensions s. This results in the following transformation matrix

```
2 * d.x / s.x | 2 * n.x / s.x * w | 0.0 | 2 * (p1.x - 0.5 * n.x * w) / s.x - 1.0
-----------------------------------------------------------------
-2 * d.y / s.y | -2 * n.y / s.y * w | 0.0 | -2 * (p1.y - 0.5 * n.y * w) / s.y + 1.0
-----------------------------------------------------------------
0.0       | 0.0                   | 0.0 | 0.0
-----------------------------------------------------------------
0.0       | 0.0                   | 0.0 | 1.0
```

(or the transpose depending on whether you want to left-multiply or right-multiply). This matrix can already be used for the uniform in the example.

To split this into translation/rotation/scale matrices you actually need 2 scale matrices as non-uniform scaling does not commute with rotation in general. We can split into the following 4 steps:

```
scale by (length(p2 - p1), width)
rotation by rotation matrix with columns (normalize(d), n)
scale by (2/s.x, 2/s.y)
translate by (see last column in the big matrix)
```

**Edit**

The matrix contained two mistakes:

- I missed multiplying by w in the translation part
- The second row needed to be multiplied by -1 to make sure that (0,0) is the top-left corner, not the bottom left corner.

Both have been fixed in the big matrix.

As for your issue the two things I can currently think of are:

- OpenGL matrices are column-major by default and the matrix in your array is row-major. You may need to transpose (i.e. switch between rows and columns) the matrix.
- With back-face culling, the transform may be making clockwise triangles from your square. To fix this, try to change the normal from normalize(-d.y, d.x) to normalize(d.y, -d.x), i.e. mirror it (or alternatively change the sign of all occurences of n in the matrix etc.).

Comment: In your first expression, what are `x` and `y`? Again, in your second what is `y`?

Comment: (x,y) are the coordinates of a point on the (0,0)-(1,1) square, i.e. basically the input position to the vertex shader

Comment: I've tried your matrix above but I'm not getting any results. I've added an edit to my question with the code, can you let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @NeomerArcana I edited my answer to fix some stuff. Let me know if you still have problems.

Comment: @Bas_Nieuwenhuizen it's still not quite right. The lines appears about twice as long as it should be, but it's positioned correctly. I've edited my question again to illustrate. I've tried adjusting the matrix a little but can't get it right.

Comment: @Bas_Nieuwenhuizen I've managed to, I think, solve it by dividing `d` by two and also adding it to `p1`.

Comment: @NeomerArcana You are probably using -1 to 1 for the standard square coords while I was assuming 0 to 1.  That would explain the difference.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks